# Webmatrix / Razor Getting Data out of SQL column with space in its name

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, razor, webmatrix

I have a basic WebMatrix CSHTML page where I am querying a stored procedure that returns some data. Several of the columns have spaces in them. I cannot modify the column names (not my database). Also, since I am not doing SELECT FROM I cannot do AS *New_Name* on a column. So with this code that I have where I am getting a value from a specific row / column, how can I specify a column name with a space?

```
var db = Database.Open("MyDb");
var sql = @"EXEC myProcedure";
var result = db.Query(sql);
var header_value = result.ElementAt(0);
.
.
.
@header_value.ColumnName
```

Lets say the name of the column is 'Test Column'
I tried

```
 @header_value.["Test Column"]
```

and

```
 @header_value["Test Column"]
```

and

```
 @header_value[Test Column]
```

None of this works.
Is there any way to specify this column which has a space in my application without changing the column on the back end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three ways to retrieve the value of a dynamic record column,

using the column index (e.g. `@header_value[1]`),

using the column name (e.g. `@header_value["Test Column"]`),

or using the column name as property (e.g. `@header_value.columnName`, but you can't use this method if the column name has spaces).

I don't know why the column name method doesn't work with you. Do you receive any error message?

Anyway, you could look at the column names of your dynamic record with a snippet like this:

```
<div>
    @foreach(var col in header_value.Columns){
        <p>@col</p>
    }
</div>
```